# How to handle this webelement?

Tags: java, selenium

I have this situation. I am building a test framework in Selenium Webdriver,TestNG using Page Object design pattern.
I have following situation. I am not sure how do I handle this in my framework.

I have Webelement(text Box)  in web page whose position will change depending on certain condition. I have attached screenshot for better understanding.[image: ScreenShot-1]

I am trying to enter input to text box below "Qty(Target Qty)" field in the above screenshot.Actually its a table. But position of "Qty(Target Qty)" & text box below it change depending on some scenarios. See the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot2]

What is the best way to handle this using Page Object design pattern?

I thought of doing following.

- Put all the elements of table in a list.
- Iterate though list looking for "Qty(Target Qty)". When you get it enter the input in the below text box.

Comment: Paste the HTML snippet of both the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the HTML of the page, it's hard to craft an answer that will work for you but there's a sample HTML table [here](http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/) that I wrote an XPath and some code for that should help as an example.

This method takes in the row and column labels and returns the text contained in the referenced cell.

```
public String getTextFromTable(String rowLabel, String columnLabel)
{
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[count(//tr/th[.='" + columnLabel + "']/preceding::tr) - 1]/td[count(//th[.='"
            + rowLabel + "']/preceding-sibling::th)]")).getText();
}
```

You would call it like

```
getTextFromTable("Height", "Taipei 101");
```

This method is using `count()` to count the number of rows or columns before the desired label. It then uses that count as an index into the `TR` or `TH` collection to find the desired element.

Now in your case, you would write a method as part of the page object that contains the table. It would take two parameters, the column label ("Qty(Target Qty)") and the input `String`. It would use a method similar to the sample function above to find the column index and then find the `INPUT` and `sendKeys()` the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the HTML, I'm going to give a general idea in case they don't have a fixed ID.

Assuming, you might have a variable number of columns in between:

1. Iterate through the Titles ('MPN', 'CPN', etc.) to find the position
   of the title 'Qty(Target Qty)'. (Iterate through the row, and check
   which `<td>` element has 'Qty(Target Qty)'. Don't forget to keep a
   counter.)
2. This will give you an idea of how many columns exist between 'MPN' and 'Qty(Target Qty)'.
3. Now, assume there are 'n' columns in between. Iterate through the row (below the title), and go to the 'n'th element. If these are `<td>` tags, then go to the 'n'th `<td>` item in the 2nd `<tr>` and search for the input box.

Assuming the number of columns in between is always 2 or 3 (as seen in the screenshot), skip step 1 from above and directly just go to step 3.